# Curved image borders

Tags: css

Still on the quest to find a way to achieve curved image, such as this one:

[image]

border-radius property does not produce desired result. Every help appreciated.

Comment: Did you actually spell it as *border-radious*?

Comment: Yes, spelling mistake. But what difference does it make?

Comment: This might work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Comment: Pos the code you tried that didn't work.

Comment: You think it should work even if you mis-spell the property name?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the desired effect with the `border-radius` css property. Here is an example:

```css
.main{
  text-align: center;
}
.rnd-img{
  border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img class='rnd-img' src="https://picsum.photos/300/200">
</div>
```

You can play with the border radius amounts to achieve the desired effect.

**UPDATE**

Since the OP went with clip-path rather than border radius I'll add some information about that CSS property here.

From the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path):

> The clip-path CSS property creates a clipping region that sets what
> part of an element should be shown. Parts that are inside the region
> are shown, while those outside are hidden.

Since that is a little vague I've created a little tool to allow you to play around with the various clip-path options

```js
var basicShapeDefaultSizes = {
    inset:"50px 50px",
  circle:"50px at 0 100px",
  ellipse:"130px 140px at 10% 20%",
  polygon:"50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%",
  path:"'M0.5,1 C0.5,1,0,0.7,0,0.3 A0.25,0.25,1,1,1,0.5,0.3 A0.25,0.25,1,1,1,1,0.3 C1,0.7,0.5,1,0.5,1 Z'"
};

var basicShapeSelect = document.getElementById("basic-shape");
var basicShapeSizeInput = document.getElementById("basic-shape-size");

basicShapeSizeInput.addEventListener('input', function handleChange(event) { 
    var clipPathStyle = basicShapeSelect.value+"("+basicShapeSizeInput.value+")";
  document.getElementById("target-img").style.clipPath = clipPathStyle;
});

basicShapeSelect.addEventListener('change', function handleChange(event) { 
  basicShapeSizeInput.value = basicShapeDefaultSizes[event.target.value];
  event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
  event.initEvent("input", true, true);
  event.eventName = "input";
  basicShapeSizeInput.dispatchEvent(event);
});

event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
event.initEvent("input", true, true);
event.eventName = "input";
basicShapeSizeInput.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```css
.half-width{
  width:48%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}
.vta-top{
  vertical-align:top;
}
input,select{
  width:100%;
}
.rnd-img{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='half-width vta-top'>
    <h2>Options</h2>
    <label for="basic-shape">Basic Shape:</label>
    <select id="basic-shape">
      <option>inset</option>
      <option>circle</option>
      <option>ellipse</option>
      <option>polygon</option>
      <option>path</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label for='basic-shape-size'>Base Shape Size</label>
    <input type='text' id='basic-shape-size' value='50px 50px'>
  </div>
  <div class='half-width'>
    <img class='rnd-img' id='target-img' src="https://picsum.photos/300/200">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: border-radius (or border-radious for more detail-oriented) actually did not work. But clip-path is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @SebastianSzydlowski glad you figured it out.

Comment: @SebastianSzydlowski So border-radius didn't work and clip-path did, yet you accepted an answer that only mentions border-radius?

Comment: clip-path is mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: @SebastianSzydlowski I have added information about the clip-path to my answer now.